# New Window Opens In Background From MouseDoubleClick Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `MouseDoubleClick` event handler defined in a `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` definition as such:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="MyClass_MouseDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The event handler is defined as:

```
private void MyClass_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem listViewItem = (ListViewItem)sender;
    MyClass senderItem = (MyClass)(listViewItem.Content);
    EditFile editFileWindow = new EditFile(senderItem);
    editFileWindow.Show();
}
```

This works as expected with the exception that the new window displays behind my main application window when it pops up. How can I set focus to the new window after it's loaded?

I tried adding `this.Focus()` at the end of my window's class constructor but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
editFileWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

By just invoking ShowDialog() you're blocking the main UI thread.

Try invoking it trough Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, like this:

```
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( new Action( () => editFileWindow.Show()));
```